# Why gmail source code does not show any html?

Tags: javascript, html, json, gmail, obfuscation

In chrome browser if you try to look in to the page source (`ctrl+u` say source code of inbox page) of Gmail it does not show you the HTML code, instead there is lot of JavaScript code mostly JSON formatted or so. Though you can see html head and meta tags.

My question is:

1. Are they trying to hide their code?
2. Do they use some kind of JavaScript templating to improve the performance?
3. Is it one of the best practices to send response in form of JavaScript objects for some kind of improvement?

Comment: They generate the DOM using Javascript. Also search for tags like <div> they are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> are they trying to hide their code?

To some degree.  They use Closure Compiler to minimize and obfuscate their code.

http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2009/11/introducing-closure-tools.html

> Millions of Google users worldwide use JavaScript-intensive applications **such as Gmail**, Google Docs, and Google Maps. Like developers everywhere, Googlers want great web apps to be easier to create, so we've built many tools to help us develop these (and many other) apps. We're happy to announce the open sourcing of these tools, and proud to make them available to the web development community.
>
> **Closure Compiler**
>
> Closure Compiler is a JavaScript optimizer that **compiles web apps down into compact, high-performance JavaScript code.**

---

> Do they use some kind of JavaScript templating to improve the performance?

Yes.  From that same link

> **Closure Templates**
>
> Closure Templates grew out of a desire for web templates that are precompiled to efficient JavaScript.  Closure Templates have a simple syntax that is natural for programmers.  Unlike traditional templating systems, you can think of Closure Templates as small components that you compose to form your user interface, instead of having to create one big template per page.

---

> Is it one of the best practices to send response in form of JavaScript objects for some kind of improvement?

If you're trying to write a rich JavaScript client then your best bet is to decompose your application into JavaScript objects.

Answer (score 1):

A complex web application like Gmail generates most of its page content dynamically using JavaScript.  The HTML that you receive from the server is mostly just the initial content to be displayed while the scripts load.

Comment: I am aware of this functionality and heard a discussion on it somewhere in google's youtube dev channel ... are you aware of any other sites that use ajax this heavily or is gmail a one off in that respecet?

Comment: I'm sure there are many sites that use AJAX as heavily as Gmail, but generating page content dynamically doesn't even require AJAX.  Take a look at the documentation and examples for [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs):  the HTML file can be as little as some `<script>` tags and an empty `<body>`, with everything else generated by JS, even if no AJAX is used for loading data.

Answer (score -1):

1) They are not hiding their code. They are using Ajax for their forms to display. So when used Ajax everything we need to manipulate with JavaScript. That is reason you see more JavaScript. Instead of Html Tags.

2) The basic fundamental is Ajax.

3) Depends on your application you can use the JavaScript object to send the data. Always this is not good practice. JavaScript is client-side scripting. While using JavaScript be careful and check with security of the application.